# same duplicate values in a separate array php

Tags: php

**php:**

```
$arr = array(1=>'1233',2=>'12334',3 =>'Hello' ,4=>'Hello' ,5 =>'awesome' ,6 =>'awesome' ,7 =>'UK');

// Convert every value to uppercase, and remove duplicate values
$withoutDuplicates = array_unique(array_map("strtoupper", $arr));

$duplicates = array_diff($arr, $withoutDuplicates);
print_r($duplicates);


foreach ($duplicates as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ":" . $key. ' ';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => Hello
    [4] => Hello
    [5] => awesome
    [6] => awesome
)
Hello:3 Hello:4 awesome:5 awesome:6
```

check online:
    http://writecodeonline.com/php/

I need to get duplicate values keys in a separate array.
**for example:**

```
array1 includes 3,4 for Hello.
array2 includes 5,6 for awesome.
```

the above code can output duplicate values and also can get their keys. Now i want to put duplicate values keys in a array.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a question?

Comment: You seem to be well on your way. What did you try for the last step?

Comment: What do you want exactly to get. Please show desired output with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question properly, you want to get the array keys of the duplicate array values for each array?

This can be done with the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function and provide it the optional search parameter.

```
/*
 * A side note: you do not have to specify the array index if their are numerical. PHP 
 * will do that for you.
 */ 
$array = array('1233', '12334', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'awesome', 'awesome', 'UK');


$keys   = [];
$unique = array_unique($array);

foreach($unique as $search) {

    $found = array_keys($array, $search);

    /*
     * If array_keys provided more than two results duplicate array values must exist.
     */
    if(count($found) > 1) {
        $keys[strtoupper($search)] = $found;
    }

}

var_dump($keys);
```

This will result in associative array where the array index is the value searched for and the array value is an array of all the keys.

```
array (size=2)
  'HELLO' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 4
  'AWESOME' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 6
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$keys = array_keys($duplicates);
```